# C#でIE11で保持しているCookie情報を取得したい

Tags: c#

タイトルの通りです。
Googleで検索しても自分で見つける事ができなかったため、こちらで質問させていただきます。
開発中のWebアプリケーションがIEの別のタブで開いているページのCookieを取得したいです。

どなたかご教授よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「別のタブで開いているページ」と同じドメインを取得する、ハイジャックする、プロキシサーバーで盗聴する、という手段があると思います。が・・？

Comment: 「IEの別のタブで開いているページ」とはアプリケーションとは無関係の任意のページでしょうか、それともアプリケーションの一部または一部ではないが同じドメインとかそういうものでしょうか。あと、cookieの仕組みの基本的なところは理解されてますか？詳細を質問を編集して追記してください。

Comment: 「別のタブで開いている」とは別のWebアプリケーションです。 cookieの基本的な仕組みとは… ブラウザがもつテキスト情報(Domainや有効期限なども含む)という認識です。